# Spark Stateful Streaming with DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Is it possible to use DataFrame as a State / StateSpec for Spark Streaming? The current StateSpec implementation seems to allow only key-value pair data structure (mapWithState etc..).

My objective is to keep a fixed size FIFO buffer as a StateSpec that gets updated every time new data streams in. I'd like to implement the buffer in Spark DataFrame API, for compatibility with Spark ML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure you can do this with Spark Streaming, but with the newer `Dataframe`-based Spark *Structured* Streaming you can express queries that get  updated over time, given an incoming stream of data.

You can read more about Spark Structured Streaming [in the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html).

If you are interested in interoperability with SparkML to deploy a trained model, you may also be interested in [this article](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/deploying-machine-learning-models-using-spark-structured-streaming/).

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies.

Comment: The link https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/deploying-machine-learning-models-using-spark-structured-streaming/ does not work anymore and I cannot find it on another place.